# Put a navigation controller in a tabbar controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have tried to add a navigation controller to a tab bar controller but the tab appear black.

My code:
AppDelegate.m

```
#import "SettingsNavigationControllerViewController.h"
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2, *viewController3;
    SettingsNavigationControllerViewController *viewController4;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [UINavigationController alloc];

    viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController3 = [[ShareViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShareViewController" bundle:nil];

    SettingsViewController *settingViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController4 = [[SettingsNavigationControllerViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingViewController];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, navigationController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is because you added a navigationcontroller with no **RootViewController** and even doesnt initialized. Thats why the  view appears as black. May be you mean to add **viewController4** instead of **navigationController** . So change your code as below

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, viewController4];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create the navigation controllers with rootviewcontrollers

```
 viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];


 viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
```

Then instantiate the Tab Bar controller like this

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController1, navigationController2, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Navigation Controllers first.

```
UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstSteps alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    nav1.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, nil];


 UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[Profiles alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    nav2.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController2, nil];
```

Then initialize your tabbar controller like this.

```
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2 ,nil];

    self.window.rootViewController=self.tabBarController;
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey mate please visit the below link for tab bar example.

I think this is good and nice example which would be helpful to you.

https://github.com/alikaragoz/AKTabBarController

You only have to set your controllers name in appDelegate.m file